# how to determine if process is idle in C

Tags: c, linux, kernel, pid, context-switch

How can I know that a process is being idle ?

Let say my program spawns n number of processes, I would like to know if any of them are sitting idle so I can ask them to do additional work,
but the problem is how to determine if a process was idle during its allocated time slice.

I can find cpu utilization ((total time - idle time)/ total time) across the system but don't know how can I get it for a process.

Since (correct me if I am wrong) a process if idle in a time slice, would voluntarily give up the remaining cpu time so getting cpu time for that process is no good.

A possible solution could be to see if voluntary context switches count increased (lets say over a threshold) but I have to work with kernel lower than 2.6.23 so reading /proc/pid/status for voluntary_context_switches & nonvoluntary_context_switches is not an option for me...

Any suggestions...

NOTE:
The example that I gave above is an over simplification. IPC is not an option. The process on a particular call should be able to determine if it was sitting idle. Tracking this at all the places where the process spends time is not feasible.

Bottom line, I want to look at some kernel stat to determine if this particular process was sitting and do some stuff based on this info.

Comment: Worker processes should tell the manager process when they're done with their previous task.

Comment: Or you could just have a queue that all the worker processes take tasks from. When a worker is done with its last task, it just reads the next task from the queue.

Comment: This is like the dictionary definition of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Barmar appreciate you response mate but maybe I wasn't clear enough. Please read my edited question.

Comment: I don't understand your whole model. How are you going to give a task to a worker if it's not actually waiting for it? Just being idle isn't enough, you need a way to tell it what to do, and that involves IPC.

Comment: See, process A would signal that its was more or less idle since the last communication with B (determined based on the answer to the question). based on this info, Process B would determine that whether or not A should be given some extra work. FYI: A and B are totally unrelated and there are multiple As and Bs

Comment: What does "more or less idle" mean? Either it's doing something or it isn't. How are they sending these signals to each other without using IPC?

Comment: I still don't understand why this isn't a perfect job for a message queue. All the A's put work in the queue, when a B is idle it reads the next piece of work from the queue.

Comment: If A and B communicated after 5 secs, A might be busy for 2sec idle for 3sec. That is what I meant by more or less idle

Comment: Are you trying to compare different A's, so you give the job to the one that's more idle? What difference does it make? All processes are interchangeable.

Comment: See a message queue already is present between A and B but if A has to send a different message if it wasn't very busy (logic based on earlier comment), how to do that ? that is the question. Message queue is not the problem, how to get info to decide which signal to send is the problem. Now how can B to that if A is the one who is sending the signal ?

Comment: I think you need to update your question with detailed pseudo-code of the design of this. I admit that I haven't written much master/worker code, but this doesn't seem anything like what I've read about the normal way to design it.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "very busy". A process is 100% busy while it's working on a task. Eventually it finishes the task, then it's 0% busy. It doesn't matter how long it has been since it became idle. All idle processes are candidates for work.

Comment: Thanks for the effort man but you are highly oversimplifying this. A process if working asynchronously can have multiple handles open and to say that if its idle is candidate for work is absolutely unjust. There maybe idle process that a complex program would not like to give work to as their respective task may not be that important at this moment.

Comment: It seems like you're looking for a criteria that's impossible to determine. The idle percentage isn't relevant. You want to avoid giving work to a process that has something more important to do, but that depends on what it will be doing when something else comes along on one of those other handles. That means you have to predict the future, not look to the past.

Comment: no its not correct. We are digressing from the topic. What to do with the async handles or which one to schedule is clearly not the question. The question is how can I calculate idle percent for a process ? Why its not relevant ?  I want to decide what is important based on this value. If the process is already doing something, I can block that and start one that handle something else...

Comment: OK. `top` can determine the idle time, it can also tell whether a process is sleeping or blocked. I guess it gets this information from `/proc/<pid>`. You can do the same thing.

Comment: Please *edit your question* to explain more and **give some context and motivations**.

Answer (score 3):

You can read /proc/*pid*/stat -- the 3rd field (read with `scanf("%*s %*[^)]) %c", &state)`) is a single character for the process's current state:

```
R - running
S - sleeping in interruptable wait
D - waiting in uninterruptable disk sleep
Z - zombie (exited)
T - traced or stopped
W - paging wait
```

If the process is stopped waiting for a sleep or I/O, it will be in state `S`

Answer (score 2):

Your program is [forking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) (not spawning) processes. In other words, your program should use [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) not [posix_spawn](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/posix_spawn.html) to start the other processes.

Then your program knows the PID of its child process (it is the result of `fork`) and it should keep them.

Once you know the PID of a process, e.g. 1234, use `/proc/1234/` to query information about that process. See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html); in particular your program could read `/proc/1234/status` and `/proc/1234/stat` etc .... Your program needs to open, read sequentially, and close these pseudo-files (and this is quick, no disk IO is involved).

However, I believe it is the wrong approach. You'll better use some [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s to those processes, and have an [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop), testing e.g. with [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) which pipe is readable and writable. Very probably busy child processes will have their input pipe non-writable (since full) in the monitoring process.

BTW, you should consider upgrading your kernel.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use WMI in windows to check the process CPU stats
In Unix, you need to run commands like top find the process CPU utilization

Or if these processes are managed by a master process which actually created them, it needs to maintain the idle and used processes similar to threadpool

Comment: Please read the question again, I can find process cpu utilization but the point is how to find the "idle" time. An idle process would just show 0% utilization and and this can also be the case for a sleeping, blocked process. How would you differentiate between them.

Comment: Process itself should be able to find this, master cannot maintain queue

Comment: The only time a process is idle is when it's sleeping or blocked. What other kind of idleness is there?

Comment: Sorry I mean blocked and sleeping are the two case, how to distinguish between them from top. That "also" shouldn't be there. My bad

Comment: So you want to give work to a sleeping process, but not to a blocked process, because the blocked process will be busy when it unblocks. That's it? But you said that A signals B when it's idle; a blocked process won't send a signal.

Comment: Again communication are at intervals so the whole idea is to find that during this interval how much time was the process idle now if we can't differentiate between blocked and idle, then the decision is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is over engineering for your requirement but one approach is to access task_struct structure in kernel from user space with help of a kernel module. This would give you complete info of a process with the help of the process pid. You can have a look at the task_struct structure definition in the kernel source at below link. If you can give us more details of what you are trying to do, it will help us share something feasible.

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1224

Comment: I won't go that way. I believe OP wants a user-land solution.